# Unable to get a HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, http, http-headers

I have written the following code on Visual Studio. I have been newly working on http protocols to study how they function...

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;

namespace GenerateHttp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
     {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Loadurl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetAsync(txtUrl.Text);
        }

        private async void GetAsync(string txtUrl)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUrl))
            {
                using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())  //httpclient
                {
                    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,txtUrl)) 
                    {
                        request.Headers.Authorization = null;
                        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpclient.SendAsync(request))
                        {
                            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("URL Connected");  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new HttpResponseException(
                                 request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Bad Connection"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a  URl");
            }
```

I was figuring out on getting a HttpStatusCode above but it doesnt seem to give me the output i want, on the contrary Im getting the unhandled execption error "The remote name could not be resolved" i.e. i mean when i deliberately enter a non responsive URL

How to resolve the same..

Comment: Looks like the code is behaving as expected. You're checking if the status code is 200(OK). If it is, showing a MessageBox. If its not, throwing an HttpResponseException. But where are you catching the exception? If there is no try catch block that is catching your HttpResponseException it will result in an Unhandled Exception.
Try changing the throw new HttpResponseException, to something like MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode);

Comment: The `HttpStatusCode` enum represents the status code *returned by the server* in response to a request. If you can't connect to the server and send the request, there's not going to be a response, nor a code to represent as `HttpStatusCode`. You need to catch the exception.

Comment: I feel the HttpResponseException should handle the exception unless a `console.writeline` is missing to complete the job..